# Prisma get all tree

Tags: mysql, node.js, hierarchical-data, prisma

I'm using Prisma new project. I've Category recursive relation :

```
model Category {
  id          Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  children    Category[] @relation("CategoryToCategory")
  parentId    Int?
  parent      Category? @relation(fields: [parentId], references: [id])
}
```

This relation work nice, but for get all categories with all children (full tree, not only 1 level), i don't know if it's possible with Prisma ? It's generally called **eager loading**.

With this request, i get only first children, but i would like get very all tree, do you know if it's possible ?

```
const allCategories = await db.category.findMany({
    include: {
      parent: true, // return only first level
      children: true, // return only first level
    },
  })
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you would need to explicitly specify how many levels you require in `include` as Prisma doesn't support [fetching recursive relations](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/4562).

Another option if you're using Postgres is to use a recursive CTE (via `with`).

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#include-deeply-nested-relations). It shows how what you want to achieve is possible, but may become a little annoying for deep relations. Here is an example:

```js
const allCategories = await db.category.findMany({
  include: {
    parent: true,
    children: {
      include: {
        category: true
      }
    }
  }
})
```